# The use of the verb "cause" in the sentence

Tags: word-usage

> In serious cases of viral encephalitis, they can **cause** headaches, high fevers, lethargy, convulsions, delirium, coma, and even death.

I'd like to know whether the use of the verb "cause" in the sentence is grammatically correct. Thanks a million.

Comment: The pronoun "they" has no referent. I understand that you wanted "they" to mean "cases of encephalitis", but the structure of your sentence leaves "they" on its own.

Comment: Yes, just shorten to "Serious cases of viral encephalitis can cause headaches, high fevers, lethargy, convulsions, delirium, coma, and even death."

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is grammatically correct if the listener knows what the pronoun "they" refers to or stands for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as @Khan says, it is grammatically correct if it is known what *they* refers to.

Further elaborating on why it is correct, you need to know that **can** is a *modal verb* here indicating **possibility**. In your sentence, it says *they can cause headaches, high fevers, lethargy, convulsions, delirium, coma, and even death*. This list of adverse effects is a **possibility** - not an obligation or a conclusion.

More examples of modal verbs [here](http://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-modals.php).